# Difference between odsi and odi

Tags: database, web-services, oracle

I'm starting to study Oracle Data Service Integration (**ODSI**), but on Oracle site's, I just found a guide on Oracle Data Integration (**ODI**).
What is the difference ? Can somone post some link to some tutorial or to blogs in order to address my doubt ?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Data Services is the new marketing name for Data Integrator. But it is the same. When you talk about sales packages, we tend to name Data Integrator the ETL portion of Data Services, Data Quality the FirstLogic portion and use the name Data Services for both. But really, it is the same installer, the same application, the same everything,....except the license keys you get enable some transforms in the one and not the other.

SOURCE: http://forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?t=133168&sid=3c1b52f525e98112d6564cf21d47fc6c

Answer (score 3):

Oracle Data Service Integrator (ODSI) is Data Federation Tool Came from the BEA Product stack previously  Aqualogic Data Services Platform (formaly ALDSP).

Oracle Data Integrator ODI is ELT (ETL) tool came from Synopsis product stack previously known as Synopsis.

Oracle have combined the ODSI to ODI Group of products. Till 10g it is available in ORACLE but in 11g ODSI tool is not available so far. Thanks.